# How to work with settings in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to keep some global settings for my project in Django. I need to have access to these settings from the code. For example, I need to set a current theme for my site that I can set using admin console or from the code. Or I need to set a tagline that will show in the header of all pages. I suppose I should use models for keeping the settings but I can't realize how I should better do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite some packages that store settings in models, pick the one that works best for you:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=django+settings&submit=search

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with changing these setting programmatically via `settings.py` you should do that. However, if you want to change these settings via the Admin Console, you should use models.